# Vagrant up error - Windows

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox

using Windows 10 with Vagrant 1.8.1 and Virtual box 5.0.14 but having some issues getting it actually set up, ran into a few errors (some fixed) this one seems to be more problematic.
[image]

No idea what causes this, and any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686280)

Comment: @pticawr Followed those steps however same issue occurs, tried it with just the regular windows cmd but didnt make a difference unfortunately.