# There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`

Tags: laravel, vagrant, git-bash, homestead

My laravel project was working yesterday properly. But today when I gave `"homestead up"`
I got following error.

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["modifyvm", "52b79407-0736-482d-86aa-596388cf3668", "--natpf1", "delete", "ssh", "--natpf1", "delete", "tcp33060", "--natpf1", "delete", "tcp44300", "--natpf1", "delete", "tcp54320", "--natpf1", "delete", "tcp8000"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Code E_FAIL (0x80004005) - Unspecified error (extended info not available)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Write)" at line 493 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp
```

I know this question is similar to [There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant for controlling VirtualBox. windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686280/there-was-an-error-while-executing-vboxmanage-a-cli-used-by-vagrant-for-contr) this question. But the solution provided here could not help me.

Answer (score 1):

> `LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Write)`

Most probably you have another process running which locks the VM run

```
ps -ef | grep -i "vbox"
```

to find out other processes -

you could also try to force the start of the VM through

```
vboxmanage startvm 52b79407-0736-482d-86aa-596388cf3668 --type emergencystop
```

Make sure the VM starts from VirtualBox (not vagrant yet) and then shutdown it down form VirtualBox correctly, next `vagrant up` should work as normal