# `Vagrant up ` issue

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am using Vagrant Up command to run but I always get this error

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "0cda9586-5016-446e-880e-fae72f66dae4", "--type", 
"headless"]

 Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 
'website_default_1539955305061_15994' has terminated unexpectedly 
during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), 
component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

I am using Mac high sierra. I downloaded image from here https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html

Does anyone knows how to solve

Comment: check this thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686280/there-was-an-error-while-executing-vboxmanage-a-cli-used-by-vagrant-for-contr

Comment: checked did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to download the latest version of VirtualBox since the older version is not supported by the latest MacOs version(10.14)

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

---

Also, the vagrant need to update for supporting the latest VirtualBox

Latest Version: 2.2.1

To upgrade to the latest version, visit the downloads page and
download and install the latest version of Vagrant from the URL
below:

https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html

---

oh, one more thing, you may also want to update the vagrant plugin:

`vagrant plugin update`