# There was an error while executing `VBoxManage` ( VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component )

Tags: vagrant

Getting below error while running `vagrant up`

There was an error while executing "VBoxManage", a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

`Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 95 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Open terminal and run blow command to solve your problem.

```
sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart
```

Comment: This worked for me. But before it worked, it kept failing with this error
_Error: Failed to load /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxDrv.kext_.

Allowing virtual box via system preferences fixed this error.
 System Preferences → Security & Privacy → General

Comment: Mac OS Big Sur, virtual box is not listed in system pref -> security & privacy -> general

Comment: Big Sur, system pref -> security & privacy -> general -> unlock to make changes -> advanced -> approve and reboot

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug with latest version of VirtualBox, for now there are two possible solution

1. Disable hyper v

OR

2. Downgrade VirtualBox

Check the thread below will give you more idea.

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=104175&p=507408

Answer (score -1):

I am able to fix the issue implement the following steps:

1. Uninstall VirtualBox via their official uninstaller script
2. Do a clean install of VirtualBox using VirtualBox.pkg
3. Adjust the privacy settings of Big Sur: System Preferences > Security and Privacy > click the unlock button

Answer (score -1):

If you are on a windows machine, then realize that VirtualMachinePlatform must be disabled if we want to start a virtual machine on windows using Oracle Virtual box to run. Oracle uses a different hypervisor I guess.

You can check that by running the following **PowerShell** command as **Admin**.

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $("VirtualMachinePlatform")
```

To disable it, run the following **PowerShell** command as an **Administrator**.

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $("VirtualMachinePlatform")
```

You may have to restart your windows machine.

You may need other things also. But this is mandatory.