# Having trouble using Ansible to deploy Quantum Mobile to AWS EC2 Instance. I'm not sure how to configure a setting called "vagrant" or "vagrant-ssh"

Tags: ansible, vagrant

Here is the feedback in the shell. I'm not sure how to configure or install this vagrant thing. I couldn't find any clear instructions online. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  (quantum_env) user@localComputer quantum-mobile % tox -e ansible -- --extra-vars "build_hosts_aws"



...
ansible run-test: commands[0] | ansible-playbook playbook-build.yml --extra-vars build_hosts_aws
[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use
-vvvv to see details

PLAY [Install ansible prerequisites] *******************************************

TASK [test configuration] ******************************************************
Sunday 14 February 2021  14:00:22 -0500 (0:00:00.040)       0:00:00.040 *******
ok: [vagrant-ssh] =>
  msg: RUNNING PLAYBOOK FOR 'Quantum Mobile' VERSION '20.11.2a'

TASK [testing ansible environment] *********************************************
Sunday 14 February 2021  14:00:22 -0500 (0:00:00.029)       0:00:00.070 *******
ok: [vagrant-ssh] =>
  msg: Connecting to host 'vagrant-ssh' as user 'vagrant'

TASK [Make local dist folder] **************************************************
Sunday 14 February 2021  14:00:22 -0500 (0:00:00.034)       0:00:00.105 *******
ok: [vagrant-ssh]

TASK [marvel-nccr.ansible_prerequisites : update cache] ************************
Sunday 14 February 2021  14:00:23 -0500 (0:00:00.369)       0:00:00.475 *******
fatal: [vagrant-ssh]: UNREACHABLE! => changed=false
  msg: 'Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Can''t open user config file vagrant-ssh: No such file or directory'
  unreachable: true

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
vagrant-ssh                : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Sunday 14 February 2021  14:00:23 -0500 (0:00:00.026)       0:00:00.501 *******
===============================================================================
Make local dist folder -------------------------------------------------- 0.37s
testing ansible environment --------------------------------------------- 0.03s
test configuration ------------------------------------------------------ 0.03s
marvel-nccr.ansible_prerequisites : update cache ------------------------ 0.03s
ERROR: InvocationError for command /Users/user/quantum-mobile/.tox/ansible/bin/ansible-playbook playbook-build.yml --extra-vars build_hosts_aws (exited with code 4)
___________________________________ summary ____________________________________
ERROR:   ansible: commands failed
```

UPDATE: I was able to install Vagrant from the link but I was not able to correctly install VirtualBox. When I try to do `vagrant up` I get the following error message

(quantum_env) localhost:quantum-mobile user$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-18.04' version '202012.21.0' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 95 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation

[Prerequisites & Installation](https://quantum-mobile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developers/build-vagrant.html#prerequisites-installation)

```sh
Vagrant >= 2.0.1
VirtualBox >= 6.1.6
Python >= 3.6
```

You can install vagrant from here [Installing Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/installation#installing-vagrant) and `VirtualBox` from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

Once you install `vagrant` and `VirtualBox`  you can launch the machine on your by

```sh
vagrant up
```

There is a `Vagrantfile` in the main repo for `ansible-playbooks`.

After that you can simply can configure `vagrant-ssh` as described in the [documentation](https://quantum-mobile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developers/build-vagrant.html#continuing-a-failed-build)

```sh
vagrant ssh-config > vagrant-ssh
tox -e ansible
```

Depending on how you want to run the `ansible-playbook` you need to modify few parameters in [inventory](https://github.com/marvel-nccr/quantum-mobile/blob/9c479d0dadf1189faf7c3935d2b3d7211a684937/inventory.yml#L63)

The error you see stems from the following configuration in the `inventory`

```yaml
vagrant-provision:
    # this private network IP will be created by `vagrant up`
    cloud_platform: virtualbox
    ansible_host: 192.168.111.222
    ansible_user: vagrant
vagrant-ssh:
    # requires first running `vagrant ssh-config > vagrant-ssh`
    cloud_platform: virtualbox
    ansible_host: default
    ansible_ssh_common_args: "-F vagrant-ssh"
    ansible_user: vagrant
```

If you want to use `aws` machine you need to update the IP address here.

```yaml
    # To connect to VMs you should change the host IP and provide an SSH key file
aws:
    cloud_platform: aws
    ansible_host: 34.227.10.49  # change this
    ansible_ssh_common_args: -i ./keys/quantum-mobile.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
    ansible_user: ubuntu
    vm_headless: true
    add_user_public_key: "{{ lookup('file', './keys/user-key.pub') }}
```

For launching the instance you can refer [here](https://github.com/marvel-nccr/quantum-mobile/blob/15ac46e43c1cd6c174ec6df7cb6922d2343b6975/docs/releases/cloud/20.05.0.md#L15)

Seems like the like the link to launch instance is broken.

You can follow this to [Launch an Amazon EC2 Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstarts/latest/vmlaunch/step-1-launch-instance.html)

Comment: I was able to get vagrant installed. But now it won't properly install VirtualBox for Mac OS X (currently trying to from the GUI and it says there is an error)

Comment: @PineappleThursday. there are install instructions available for [Installing on Mac OS X Hosts](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html). You can try restarting by `sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restar` command. [Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/1671)

Comment: There is not directory VirtualBox in StartupItems. I followed the instructions, but it doesn't seem to work properly. I can open VirtualBox from my applications, but then I get this error code except it's not telling me that it's blocking anything from Oracle (yes I tried uninstalling and reinstalling).

https://www.howtogeek.com/658047/how-to-fix-virtualboxs-“kernel-driver-not-installed-rc-1908-error/

Comment: @PineappleThursday did you tried restarting the `sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart` ?? It seems to fix the exact error [VirtualBox error : kernel driver not installed(rc=-1908)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19941284/2246345)

Comment: I have. It seems that the installation did not even work properly enough for it to create that directory/file path

Comment: @PineappleThursday I am not sure what's wrong then because exact error which you have showed above seems to be resolved just by restarting [There was an error while executing `VBoxManage` ( VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component )](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59961248/2246345). What's the version of OS you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228716/discussion-between-pineapplethursday-and-samtoddler).